# Square Root of Operator forms a two sided ideal

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, compact-operators

If $H$ is an infinite dimensional separable hilbert space, define $T(H)$ as

$$A \in T(H) \qquad \text{iff} \qquad (A^*A)^{\frac{1}{2}} \, \, \text{bounded and compact} \, \, $$

and $$\sum_{i} \lambda_i((A^*A)^{\frac{1}{2}}) <\infty$$

where $\lambda_i$ are the eigenvalues with repeated multiplicity.

So clearly $(A^*A)^{\frac{1}{2}}$ is Hilbert Schmidt by a simple norm argument. Since H-S operators form a two sided ideal, how can I use this to show $T(H)$ is also a two sided ideal (in bounded operators)?

Comment: The key here is that $s_i(A):=\lambda_i(\sqrt{A^\dagger A})$ (the singular numbers of $A$) for any $S,T\in\mathcal B(\mathcal H)$ satisfy $0\leq s_i(SAT)\leq \Vert S\Vert s_i(A)\Vert T\Vert$ so $A\in T(\mathcal H)$ implies $SAT\in T(\mathcal H)$ by direct comparison test. For the stated property of the singular numbers cf. Lemma 16.6 in *"Introduction to Functional Analysis" (1997)* by Meise & Vogt.